# Http not working in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have some issue with my angular 2 project Http, I have set it in constructor as a parameter and inside the constructor it print as an undefined, bellow is the code from my project:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
import {Http, HttpModule, RequestOptions, XHRBackend} from "@angular/http";
import { Injectable }     from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class GetDataService{
private dataUrl = '/data';  // URL to web API
private req;
//mode = 'observable';
public headers;
public options;
constructor(http:Http) {
    //this.http = new Http(XHRBackend, RequestOptions);
    console.log(http);
}
}
```

---

here is my Error

> EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error in
>   http://localhost:3000/app/invoice.component.html:160:0 caused by:
>   Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

---

Component where Service used

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {GetDataService} from "./get-data.service";

@Component({
selector: 'http',
template: `<h4>response</h4>`
})

export class GetDataComponent {
response:string;
getDataService:GetDataService;
constructor(){
    this.getDataService = new GetDataService();
    console.log(this.getDataService.getData());
}
}
```

and add service in main module providers

Also when I try to inject GetDataService in constructor parameter

```
constructor(getDataService:GetDataService){
    this.getDataService = getDataService;
    console.log(this.getDataService.getData());
}
```

I get --

> Error: (SystemJS) Can't resolve all parameters for GetDataComponent

---

I have also tried to create object of Http inside constructor, but again I am getting error.

```
constructor() {
    this.http = new Http;
    console.log(this.http);
}
this is the result of above code:

Http {_backend: undefined, _defaultOptions: undefined}
```

Can anyone please help me.

Comment: "not working" is quite unclear. What is the expected behavior? What is the actual behavior? Where and how do you make the HTTP request using `http`?

Comment: I tried to send test get request in getData method in this service, but no one http.method works because http is undefined

Answer (score 0):

`Http` is not supposed to be created with `new Http()`.

Add `HttpModule` to your `@NgModule({ imports: [BrowserModule, HttpModule], ...})` and inject `Http` using the constructor as shown in your first example.

For more details see https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt6.html

Comment: when I try inject http in parameter, I get error http undefined - "Cannot read property 'get' of undefined"

Comment: Did you add `HttpModule` to `imports` as shown in my answer?

Comment: How and where is `GetDataService` injected?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code there. Code in comments is unreadable.

Comment: The code that causes this error is not included in your question "Cannot read property 'get' of undefined"